# Error "Data type mismatch in criteria or expression" while executing code relating DLookup

Tags: ms-access, types, mismatch

I get an error while executing the following code relating DLookup:

```
RightUser = DLookup("[UserRights]", "tblRights", "[FormName]=" & Me.name & " " & "And [EmplUserName]='" & TempVars(EmplUserName) & "'")
```

But this gives me the error

> Data type mismatch in criteria or expression

Any ideas on how to fix this?
I'm sure it's a minor error, but I'm really stumped!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
RightUser = DLookup("[UserRights]", "tblRights", "[FormName]='" & Me.name & "' And [EmplUserName]='" & TempVars(EmplUserName) & "'")
```